# Russel's paradox notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Can someone help me out? I don't really get what "x does not belong to x" means in this: [image: Russel's paradox]

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253818/example-of-set-which-contains-itself

Comment: It means that $X$ is not element of $X$.

Comment: If you are wondering how a set can be element of itself, it is a construct that you will never see in, say, number theory or analysis. It is one, however, that created chaos in set theory just over a century ago, and inspired various "fixes" to set theory. There was no formally stated rule that you could *not* have $x\in x$ or $x\notin x$. So why not have $S=\{x:x\notin x\}$? This led to Russell's famous paradox. You could both prove and disprove the existence of $S$ using the set theory of the day.

Answer (score 0):

In this scheme, the elements $X$ of $A$ may themselves be sets.  In fact, the set $X$ might contain *itself* as an element, so that $X \in X$.  For example, a set $Y$ satisfying $Y = \{1,2,Y\}$ contains itself.

What we are defining, then, is the set of elements $X$ (of $A$) that do *not* contain themselves.  In particular, if we take $Y$ as defined above, then $Y \notin B$.

Comment: I should rather say: **a** set $Y$ that satisfies $Y=\{1,2,Y\}$ contains itself (as element).

Comment: @drhab is the set not uniquely determined by this equality?

Comment: I don't think so. Am I wrong then? My comment was purely based on intuition. Btw, got to go now. I will come back later.

Comment: I say that $Y$ is uniquely described since we have given all of its elements.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It depends on your set theory.  In ZF set theory, there is no such $Y$.  In Peter Aczel's set theory your intuition is correct and there is a unique set $Y$ with the property you describe.

Comment: @MJD My thoughts are as follows: regardless of one's choice of set theory, the axiom of extensionality grants us that *if* such a set exists, then it is unique.

Comment: I don't see where you get that.  Suppose  the property  $Y = \{1,2,Y\}$ holds for two different entities, say $y_1$ and $y_2$.  You want to claim based on extensionality that $y_1=y_2$ because they have the same elements, but to do that you need to know $y_1=y_2$ already.

Comment: @MJD you have me there; I didn't really think it through.