# Can there be multiple sets $X$ satisfying $X = \{X\}$?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

I thought about this while answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1445085/81360).  To restate my question:

> Suppose that our axioms are such that a set $X$ exists satisfying $X = \{X\}$.  Might it be consistent that there are multiple sets satisfying this property?  Are there (well-known) axioms that guarantee existence and uniqueness?

My motivating intuition here is that in most cases, enumerating the elements of a set uniquely defines the set.  For example, I'm tempted to say that the set $\{1,2,3\}$ is unique "because we've enumerated all of its elements".  Does this intuition completely fail for these stranger sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such sets are called *Quine atoms* - see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33282/can-we-have-a-a. In ZFC, no Quine atoms exist; in Aczel's set theory, exactly one Quine atom exists; and in general we can have lots of distinct Quine atoms in NF-like set theories.

Comment: Well, that really covers it.  Thanks!