# Set that has itself as an element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Does there exist a set $A$ such that $A \in A$?**

The empty set doesn't work. Also, it seems clear that if $A$ exists, then it must be infinite.

If no such set exists, then is there a simple proof of this?

Comment: This was covered before on the site.

Comment: Why would it have to be infinite? It could just be the one-element set $A=\{A\}$.

Comment: @bof That doesn't Work. It is not true that $\{A\} \in {A}$.

Comment: @JacobMayle Obviously this is impossible with the axiom of foundation. Without that axiom, it is consistent to have sets $A=\{A\}$, have sets $A\ne B$ with $A=\{B\}$ and $B=\{A\}$, have sets $A=\{A,B\}$ with $B\ne A$, etc.

Comment: Related: [Non-well-founded set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253818/example-of-set-which-contains-itsel and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200255/is-the-statement-a-in-a-true-or-false

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: My favorite are Boffa atoms--$A=\{x: A\in x\}$--which you can get in NF.

Answer (score 3):

In NF and NFU such sets exist, and in Positive Set Theory as well; most obviously in the case of the universe $V$, $V\in V$. NF can also have objects called *Quine atoms* which are sets $A$ such that $A=\{A\}$, an object which one also finds when one replaces Foundation in ZF with Aczel's Anti-foundation axiom. But as mentioned by other answerers, ZF typically explicitly precludes such things.

Answer (score 1):

Such a set does not exist in $\sf ZFC$, with emphasis on $\sf F$.

By the [axiom of foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity), if such a set $x$ existed, then since $\{x\}$ isn't empty it would follow that there exists $y\in \{x\}$ such that $y\cap \{x\}=\varnothing$. So $y=x$, $x\in y$ and $x\in \{x\}$ contradicting $y\cap \{x\}=\varnothing$.

Comment: The emphasis on $\sf F$ is a joke, by the way.

Comment: I wasn't going to say anything...

Comment: What if $x$ contains itself and also some other members.. a,b,c...?$x=\{x,a,b,c...\}$

Comment: @MichalDvořák My proof is independent of that hypothesis. Assume $x=\{x,a,b,c\}$. Now allow me to completely ignore that assumption and allow me to consider the set $\{x\}$ (which isn't empty). From here read the rest of my proof. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Russell's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox)- right?

Comment: Not quite, I think. But see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

Comment: @DavidMitra: I think the ideas are related. These inconsistencies led to the ZFC formulation I think.

Comment: There is nothing inconsistent about sets that belong to themselves. It is not related to Russell's paradox. The theory $\mathsf{ZFC}$ explicitly rules out these sets, because they do not belong to the cummulative hierarchy, but this is a separate thing. We also explicitly rule out urelements, and they are not paradoxical either.

Comment: Yeah, if ZF minus Foundation were inconsistent with self-membership then it would refute any anti-foundation axiom, which we know isn't the case...